# How to hardcode a value in a texbox in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the below code to popup the authentication dialog.  I want to hard-code the password in my code and make it a read-only text box. What should I do?

```
IDD_LOGIN_AUTH_DIALOG DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 148, 82
 STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
 CAPTION "Authentication"
 FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
 BEGIN
LTEXT           "Host:",IDC_STATIC_HOST,7,8,36,10,SS_CENTERIMAGE | 
                NOT WS_GROUP

EDITTEXT        IDC_VNCHOST,46,7,95,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | 
                NOT WS_TABSTOP

CONTROL         108,IDC_STATIC_LOGO,"Static",SS_BITMAP,7,23,32,30

RTEXT           "User name:",IDC_STATIC_LOGIN,41,25,39,10,SS_CENTERIMAGE

EDITTEXT        IDC_LOGIN_EDIT,84,24,57,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL

RTEXT           "Password:",IDC_STATIC_PASSWD,41,42,39,10,SS_CENTERIMAGE

EDITTEXT        IDC_PASSWD_EDIT,84,41,57,12,ES_PASSWORD | ES_READONLY | 

                NOT WS_TABSTOP  

DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK",IDOK,20,61,50,14

PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,77,61,50,14

END
```

Comment: Hardcore the password?  Would that make it a password to an adult site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get full control over all fields if you use the CONTROL keyword rather than the EDITTEXT keyword, use

```
CONTROL     "mypassword", IDC_PASSWD_EDIT, "Edit", 
            ES_LEFT | WS_BORDER | ES_PASSWORD | ES_READONLY, 
            84,41,57,12
```

instead of

```
EDITTEXT    IDC_PASSWD_EDIT,84,41,57,12,ES_PASSWORD | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_TABSTOP
```

Answer (score 0):

From memory:

```
HWND hwnd = ...//handle to the dialog
::SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_STATIC_PASSWD, "YourText");
::EnableWindow(::GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_STATIC_PASSWD), FALSE);
```